# Batch Renaming All Files in Several Folders

Tags: windows, powershell

:)

Let's say in the file path, C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\Records,  there are several folders.

I want to rename all the files in all the folders by adding their respective folder names in front of their current file names.

For example, folder 1 and folder 2 exists in C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\Records. All the files in folder 1 should be renamed with "folder 1 " added in front. And all the files in folder 2 should be renamed with "folder 2 " added in front. So something like the file "Invoice" in folder 1 being renamed to "folder 1 Invoice". Same thing with folder 2.

Is there a way to do this in Powershell? Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\Records' -File -Recurse) | 
 Rename-Item -NewName {'{0} {1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name} -WhatIf
```

The `-WhatIf` switch is a precaution. With that added, the code wil only show in the console what *would* happen. If you are satisfied with that, remove the `-Whatif` switch to actually start renaming the files.

Comment: Hi! I tried it out but it doesn't seem to do anything even with the WhatIf. Do note that it is a folder with many folders with files that need the renaming :)

Comment: @ZhenYang I can't see what you are doing and if you have permission to all the files in the root folder, but for me this works as expected. (PowerShell version 5.1). As I tried to explain, **with** `-WhatIf` nothing gets renamed; it will only show you. **Without** `-WhatIf` the files are renamed. What version of PowerShell are you using? The `-File` switch is only available as of version 3.0